# Building a simple bridge between objc and lua?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, lua

I have integrated Lua with my ObjC code (iphone game). The setup was pretty easy, but now, I have a little problem with the bridging. I have googled for results, etc... and it seems there isn't anything that could work without modifications. I mean, I have checked luaobjc bridge (it seems pretty old and dicontinued), I heard about LuaCocoa but it seems not to work on iphone, and wax is too thick.

My needs are pretty spare, I just need to be able to call objc methods from lua and don't mind having to do extra work to make it work (I don't need a totally authomatic bridging system).

So, I have decided to build a little bridge myself based on this page http://anti-alias.me/?p=36. It has key information about how to accomplish what I need, but the tutorial is not completed and I have some doubts about how to deal with method overloading when called from lua, etc...

Do anybody know if there exist any working bridge between objc and lua on the iphone or if it could be so hard to complete the bridge the above site offers?

Any information will be welcomed.

Comment: A modern ObjC-Lua bridge that mimicks Apple's `JavaScriptCore` API can be found here: https://github.com/PedestrianSean/ObjC-Lua

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel!

First, you are correct that luaobjc and some other variants are outdated. A good overview can be found on the [LuaCocoa](http://playcontrol.net/opensource/LuaCocoa/other-luaobjective-c-bridge.html) page. [LuaCocoa](http://playcontrol.net/opensource/LuaCocoa/) is fine but apparently doesn't support iPhone development, so the only other choice is [Wax](https://github.com/probablycorey/wax). Both LuaCocoa and Wax are runtime bridges, which means that you can (in theory) access every Objective-C class and method in Lua at the expense of runtime performance.

For games and from my experience the runtime performance overhead is so significant that it doesn't warrant the use of any runtime binding library. From a perspective of why one would use a scripting language, both libraries defy the purpose of favoring a scripting language over a lower-level language: they don't provide a [DSL solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) - which means you're still going to write what is essentially Objective-C code but with a slightly different syntax, no runtime debugging support, and no code editing support in Xcode. In other words: runtime Lua binding is a questionable solution at best, and has lots of cons going against it. Runtime Lua bindings are particularly unsuited for fast-paced action games aiming at a constantly high framerate.

What you want is a static binding. Static bindings at a minimum require you to declare what kind of methods will be available in Lua code. Some binding libraries scan your header files, others require you to provide a special declaration file similar to a header file. Most binding libraries can use both approaches. The benefit is optimal runtime performance, and being able to actually design what classes, methods and variables Lua scripts have access to.

There are but 3 candidates to bind Lua code to an iPhone app. To be fair, there are a lot more but most have one or more crucial flaws or are simply not stable or for special purposes only, or simply don't work for iPhone apps. The candidates are:

- [tolua](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~celes/tolua/) and [tolua++](http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/)
- [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html)
- [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)

Big disadvantage shared by all Lua static binding libraries: none of them can bind directly to Objective-C code. All require to have an additional C or C++ layer available that ultimately interfaces with your Objective-C code. This has to do with how Objective-C works as a language and how small a role it has played (so far) when it comes to embedding Lua in Objective-C apps.

I recently evaluated all three binding libraries and came to enjoy SWIG. It is [very well documented](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Lua.html) but has a bit of a learning curve. But I believe that learning curve is warranted because SWIG can be used to combine nearly any programming and scripting language, it can be advantageous to know how to use SWIG for future projects. Plus, once you understand their definition file implementation it turns out to be very easy (especially when compared to luabind) and considerably more flexible than tolua.

Comment: Nice explanation. I have set this to be a correct answer because it doesn't present a final solution (it seems there's no way to get what I need at this moment) but exposes pretty nicely differnt good options and set us on the correct path. I'm looking forward to reading this tutorials!! From your explanation, I understand I need to create some "proxy classes" in c++ that will delegate the final call to ObjC object, but are this C++ methods the one exposed to lua am I right?

Comment: Exactly. The wrapper should probably be a C++ singleton class since I doubt that one would want to run multiple instances of Lua in a game at the same time.

Comment: Ok. Understood. This was my first aproximation but wanted to know if there was something like the options you suggested (static binding) for objc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

OK, bit late to the party but in case others come late also to this post here's another approach to add to the choices available: hand-code your LUA APIs.

I did a lecture on this topic where I live coded some basic LUA bindings in an hour.  Its not hard.  From the lecture I made [a set of video tutorials that shows how to get started](http://indiegamecodingconfessions.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/script-your-game-with-lua.html).

The approach of using a bindings generation tool like SWIG is a good one if you *already have exactly the APIs that you need* to call written in Objective-C and it makes sense to bring **all** those same API's over into LUA.

The pros of the hand-coding approach:

- your project just compiles with one standard Xcode target

  - your project is all C & Obj-C
  - the LUA is just data shipped along with your images
- no fiddling with "do I check in generated code" to Git
- you create LUA functions for just the things you want
- you can easily have hosted scripts that live inside an object
- the API is under your control and is well known
- dont expose engine APIs to level building team/tools

The last point is just that if you have detail functions that only make sense at the engine level and you don't want to see those when coding the game play you'll need to tell SWIG not to bind those.

Steffens answer is perfect and this approach is just another option, that may suit some folks better depending on the project.